# How to convert Time in JMeter in 24 Hr format, while using shiftTime function to convert IST to UTC format?

Tags: jmeter

Actually I'm trying to to shift the time, the application I'm working on is in UTC and I'm working in IST.

I've used both BEAN Shell pre processor and shiftTime function

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
int AddSeconds= 00; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
int AddMinutes= 392; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
int AddHours= 00; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
Date now         = new Date();
Calendar c       = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(now);
c.add(Calendar.SECOND, AddSeconds);
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, AddMinutes);
c.add(Calendar.HOUR,   AddHours);
Date NewTime        = c.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String mytime       = df.format(NewTime);

vars.put("NewTime",mytime);
```

Shift Time :
"${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z',,PT393M,,)}"

Bun when I run the HTTP Request in Jmeter the time format is coming in 12Hrs only instead of 24 Hr
Also Time shift is taking in weird manner, I've tried all options from Stackoverflow from last 2 days and unable to achieve my task to convert IST to UTC.

This is what I'm using in Jmeter Post body
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM4hi.png)

And this is what I'm getting as result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOwhA.png)

Time formats are getting totally mismatched here, can someone please help me to convert IST to UTC correctly while playing with these time formats and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use __timeShift() function for getting the date in the different timezone, it will return you the current (default) one

So if you need to add 392 minutes to the current time in the time zone different from yours - you will have to go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and use [TimeCategory](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) class

Example code:

```
${__groovy(def now = new Date(); use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 392.minute; return  nowPlusOneYear.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"\,TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST')) },)}
```

Demo:

[image]

If you need to get the time in UTC just change `IST` to `UTC`

```
${__groovy(def now = new Date(); use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 392.minute; return  nowPlusOneYear.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"\,TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')) },)}
```

More information: [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how)

Also be informed that [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one more way to do this via bean shell preprocessor and it worked for me pretty well.

Here is the code to use... here -325 minutes is the difference between IST and UTC

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
int AddSeconds= 00; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
int AddMinutes= -325; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
int AddHours= 00; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
 Date now         = new Date();
Calendar c       = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(now);
c.add(Calendar.SECOND, AddSeconds);
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, AddMinutes);
c.add(Calendar.HOUR,   AddHours);
Date NewTime        = c.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String mytime       = df.format(NewTime);

vars.put("NewTime",mytime);

// NewTime is your jmeter variable
```